# Is there a way to delete "Select" keywords from a VBA Code?

Tags: excel, vba

I have been learning VBA for days
I have a question in mind, **is** there a clever way to run something in which deletes all "select" keywords from a VBA code (assuming you don't deliberately use "select" in your code)
The reason why I am asking is, as you know, going throw macro recorded code with a bunch of "select" statements can be distracting.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is Replace from the Edit menu an option? Something like, replace select, or select. with an empty string.

Comment: Be wary of what you remove. Recorded macros tend to rely on whatever is selected.

Comment: @njc Oh replace is a new thing for me. I like its idea but it seems the issue is you can only replace the word you typed. What I optimally want, is to replace the whole line that contain this keyword.

Comment: You are a confused person. In VBA select refers to the Select case structure. What you are referring to is the Select method from Office objects.  What you need to be aware of is that recording macros is ( mostly) ok for finding out how to operate on Office objects but to write good code you need to translate select oriented operations into range based operations.

Comment: @SnowGroomer Oh no I am dumb I just realized this what you said, macros doesn't use the range object to run methods or properties, instead they use "selection". This is frustrating ...

Comment: @freeflow you are right, I just realized that now

Comment: @HussainAlqahtani .. For reference  - [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba?rq=1)

Comment: Export modules and run regex against them then re-import.

Comment: Hi, Just paste your code into free application Notepad++ or any other Txt editor and with Ctlr+F <replace> ".Select" with "" :)